# shifting the list entries to the next two or three slides

Tags: beamer, lists

I am trying to shift the list entries to the next two or three frames using `\newcounter{currentenumi}`, but I only know how to do it for the second frame, but have no idea how to do this for the third or fourth frame. Here's what I did. Could anyone show me how to continue this list in the third or fourth frame?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Sub-item 1
    \setcounter{currentenumi}{\theenumi}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 2
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{\thecurrentenumi}
    \item Sub-item 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 2
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{\thecurrentenumi}
    \item Sub-item 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Put `\setcounter{currentenumi}{\theenumi}` to the line before `\end{enumerate}` of the second frame to save the current counter again.

Comment: Also, how should they be numbered? You have `Sub-item 2` on two slides. Are they both `2`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually splitting your list across multiple frames, you could overlays, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<only@1> Item 1
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item<only@1> Sub-item 1
    \end{enumerate}
    \item<2-3> Item 2
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item<only@2> Sub-item 2
    \item<only@3> Sub-item 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]